# Error "No module named pywin32" after downloading it in anaconda

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to create a module that uploads multiple files to an email using python. The method I've elected to use is found here (https://www.codeforests.com/2020/06/05/how-to-send-email-from-outlook/) which requires that you install pywin32. I tried to do the pip install, which didn't work as it was already downloaded, but I'm still having trouble getting the module to run properly. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and I have it in Anaconda on both my base & spyder environments, but every time I run it (either JNB or Spdr) I get the same ModuleNotFoundError.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pip install pywin32` does that work?

Comment: `"provides access to many of the Windows APIs from Python." - from docs`

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Have you tried running it in your base environment?

Comment: It turns out, my problem is that in trying to run a 32bit pywin w/ 64bit python... I know you can download 32bit python to work alongside the 64bit... any recommendations on the download with heavy company security?

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. The error you mentioned, your last comment and finally your answer seem totally unrelated. It seems that you didn't share all the info.

Comment: @CristiFati Start to finish..
- I was trying to create a module that connected to our company's DB, ran sql queries and built graphs/charts/excel files, then embed/attach in an email thread.
- I came across an error which led me to assume that I needed to download pywin32, which was already downloaded to my computer... this lead me to assume I was having 32/64 bit issues.
- I kept searching after finding and found it had been resolved by someone by downgrading their python using the pip I posted in the answer... and I tried that, and it worked. 
A misdiagnosis from a new python learner.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out everything worked out whenever I downgraded the version of python I was using...

*pip install pywin32==225*

Thanks for your help, everyone!